# Rails - Capybara, populate hidden field from trix-editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, trix

I use [Trix Editor](https://github.com/maclover7/trix) to have WISIWIG in my form. I want to test with RSpec and Capybara but trix-editor put the field hidden.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <trix-editor class="formatted_content form-control" placeholder="Description" input="annonce_ad_body_trix_input_annonce_ad"></trix-editor><input type="hidden" name="annonce_ad[body]" id="annonce_ad_body_trix_input_annonce_ad" />
</div>
```

I need to know how i can fill this hidden field with Capybara to make my test pass. I have try these attemp:

```
fill_in "annonce_ad[body]", with: "my value"
find(:css, 'trix-editor').set("New text")
find("trix-editor", visible: false).set("my value")
find(:xpath, "//input[@id='annonce_ad_body_trix_input_annonce_ad']", visible: false).set "my value"
find(:xpath, "//*[@id='annonce_ad_body_trix_input_annonce_ad']", visible: false).set("value")
first('input#annonce_ad_body_trix_input_annonce_ad.class', visible: false).set("your value")
```

None of these have work for me. Someone have any idea how i can fill my body(with trix) in this case?

Answer (score 20):

When using Capybara the rule when dealing with non-standard controls is to mimic what the user would do.  In this case that would be click on the visible field (trix-editor element) and then type the contents wanted.  You should never be trying to fill in non-visible elements and in fact the `visible` option should rarely (if ever) be used when testing an app (makes some sense if using Capybara for scraping).  So in your case that should be

```
find('trix-editor').click.set('New text')
```

It would probably work without the click, but it doesn't hurt to more fully replicate the user.  Since you've stated that something very similar to that doesn't work for you (but not provided the actual error) I have to assume you're not actually using a JS capable driver.  Since `trix` is a JS driven editor you need to use a JS capable driver when testing it - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers .

The following basic ruby snippet shows Capybara filling in the demo trix editor at trix-editor.org

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

sess = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome, nil)
sess.visit('https://trix-editor.org/')
editor = sess.find('trix-editor')
editor.click.set('My test text')
editor.assert_text('My test text')
```

Comment: While this is the correct way to do this, it is worth noting that the `set` method fills in its text one character at a time (at least with Selenium webdrivers) which makes your test take considerable slower, depending on the length of the string. I ran into this when testing a maxlength of underlying field with 130k characters. Only viable option for me was to fall back to custom JS to create a tmp textarea, and copy&paste the text from there. `.send_keys([:control, 'a'])` then `c` then `v` is your (hacky) friend here :)

Answer (score 0):

I make a mistake, this work for me.

```
find(:xpath, "//*[@id='annonce_ad_body_trix_input_annonce_ad']", visible: false).set("some value here")
```

Comment: This is no different than using CSS id selector (which is much clearer for most people to read) `find('#announce_ad_body_trix_input_announce_ad', visible: false).set("some value here")`.  However, since it's interacting with a non-visible element it means your test is not really testing anything because it's doing something the user never could.

Comment: Well, he could test how the system behaves if the user fiddles with the browser inspector, but it's easier to test this with controller specs. I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965124/299774 - that's a good answer.